# Linq join group selecting different type objects by condition

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I am grouping two collections by linq and lambda expression.

```
        var result = firstCollection.GroupJoin(secondCollection,
            s => s.Id,
            p => p.Sid,
            (first, second) =>
            {
                return new { first.Id };
            });
```

This works. But I want to select by condition like this:

```
        var result = firstCollection.GroupJoin(secondCollection,
            s => s.Id,
            p => p.Sid,
            (first, second) =>
            {
                if (someCondition)
                    return new { id = first.Id };
                else
                    return new { 
                          id = first.Id, 
                          name = first.Name };
            });
```

but this gives error. How can I do this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that because you want to return a collection which has 2 different anonymous types. Do them separately and use where.

Comment: *What error* are you getting?

Comment: you can't do that because EF can't determine which type of IQueryable this is. EF can't mix two types of return objects within one query information, because the IQueryable includes type and mapping information for the queried type. you'll have to do this Selection after executing the query.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Yes I am doing after selection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can like this,

```
 var result = firstCollection.GroupJoin(secondCollection,
            s => s.Id,
            p => p.Sid,
            (first, second) =>
            {
                dynamic foo;
                if (someCondition)
                    foo = new { id = first.Id };
                else
                    foo = new { 
                          id = first.Id, 
                          name = first.Name 
                    };

                return foo;
            });
```